# Next Build = TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo') > Export encountered errors on following paths: /ArtikelStatus

Tags: javascript, next.js, redux

I making a webb app with Next JS and aim to publish the app in Docker on a Linus Server with a private registry. The app is made for a company and I cannot show you all the code because of that but I have upload a couple of files that maybe can help you to help me ;)

The file structure in:
Structure.txt

You are free to ask and if you are missing any files I can post the given part here.

The result of the Next build:
Next Build.txt

Tried:
Since the path is pointing at ArtikelStatus I have concentrated to solve the problem in Artikel Status.tsx wihtout any success. I cannot find any bigg problem in how I had program it. Something is wrong. I am open to solution :)

The [Github](https://github.com/FredrikHj/ArtikelStatusHelp.git)

Hope you can help me.

Please be kind since this is my first post here om Stackowerflow :)

Best regards Fredrik